# Jenkins could not read Username for 'https://github.****.org': No such device or address git push error

Tags: jenkins

We had a requirement where in the Jenkins pipeline we had to bump up the npm version of our NodeJS package and do a git tag git push.

For this what we had done was have a Python script that would do some task before bumping the version.
Hence we did this in our Jenkinsfile

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'username', passwordVariable: 'adminPass', usernameVariable: 'adminUser')]) {
            sh "echo https://$adminUser:$adminPass@github**** > ~/.git-credentials"
            sh "git config --local credential.helper store --file=~/.git-credentials"
```

But every time we came to the push command from our python script we got this error

```
could not read Username for 'https://github.****.org': No such device or address
```

The problem was simple error but when we tried google-ing the issue we got a wide variety of solution that did not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are stuck just check if your username or password doesn't have a '@' in it.